# A pattern to queue notifications?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a library to pop up some toast notifications and I tried to put a limit on the maximum notifications on screen.

I managed to extract the idea into a plunker (don't mind the code, it is only to solve the issue).

I have a function to create those toasts:

```
function createToast() {
  var body = $document.find('body').eq(0);

  var toast = {};
  toast.id = index++;
  toast.el = angular.element('<div class="toast">Toast ' + toast.id + '</div>');
  toast.el = $compile(toast.el)($scope);

  if (maxOpened && toasts.length >= maxOpened) {
    remove(toasts[0].id);
  }

  toasts.push(toast);
  $animate.enter(toast.el, body).then(function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        remove(toast.id);
      }, 3000);
  });
}
```

Basically it creates a new object with an `el` and then animates it out on the body. Notice that if the `maxOpened` is reached it removes the first one.

```
function remove(id) {
  var toast = findToast(id);

  if (toast) {
    $animate.leave(toast.el).then(function() {
      var index = toasts.indexOf(toast);
      toasts.splice(index, 1);
    });
  }

  function findToast(toastId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < toasts.length; i++) {
      if (toasts[i].id === id) {
        return toasts[i];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Find the toast, animate the leave and then delete it.

If I do a $interval on them, let's say `600ms` it works.

Try here: http://plnkr.co/edit/lDnT57FPadCt5Ir5wHuK?p=preview

If you lower it to something like `100ms` it starts to break, not only ignoring the max but also leaving some orphan toasts that won't get deleted.

So I am not sure what could be a good solution here. My best guess is to provide a queue so I start to drain it as soon as a toast get removed but so far, I didn't make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probably simplest solution would be to add a deferred to each toast and only start to animate the toast when the limit is not or no longer reached.

You start by adding a deferred and resolve it immediately, if the limit is not reached yet or the limit can be ignored:

```
toast.slotOpen = $q.defer();

toasts.push(toast);
if (maxOpened && toasts.length <= maxOpened || !maxOpened) { // i guess 0 or a falsy value means to ignore the limit
  toast.slotOpen.resolve();
}
```

You only start the animation, when a slot is open:

```
toast.slotOpen.promise.then(function() {
  $animate.enter(toast.el, body).then(function() {
```

The last thing to do is to resolve the deferred when a new slot gets opened after an old toast has been removed:

```
$animate.leave(toast.el).then(function() {
   var index = toasts.indexOf(toast);
   toasts.splice(index, 1);
   if (maxOpened && toasts.length >= maxOpened) {
    toasts[maxOpened - 1].slotOpen.resolve();
   }
```

I have adjusted your code and created a new [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1byInoRRE69X9JAd1S8e?p=info).

Comment: Seems like a proper solution indeed. I am going to try it on the real deal tomorrow. Your solution is not killing the first note to force a new one to appear but maybe your idea is better anyway.